# Enterprise Library Logger - Email server settings

Tags: c#, .net, enterprise-library

I'm using email trace listener to obviosuly send me emails whenever an exception occurs but testing in the production environment (outside of our network) the email doesn't work and I'm fairly certain because we don't support open relay and it doesn't look like Enterprise Library has a place to specify credentials to log in to the mail server.

How can I get around this?

Edit: Enterprise Library 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of enterprise library are you using?

EntLib 5.0 supports authenticated email.

Alternatively you could use this http://authemailtracelisten.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set values with:

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="testuser@domail.com">
      <network password="password" userName="userName" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

I hope this will help to you.

But even better would be if you could separate logging framework from your application with Common.Logging lib. Then you can use any lib that Common.Logging support or write own adapter.

Comment: Does this work with Enterprise Logger Block? I'd imagine so if Enterprise Library is a Micrososft product then it makes sense they would use .NET to do the work. But then again...

Comment: [Common.Logging](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/docs/2.0.0/reference/html/index.html) currently supports log4net, nlog and Enterprise Library(versions 3.1 and 4.1). But it seems little old. I had to recompile it to support nlog 2.0 which I prefer